# Updating rows with a sub-query involved Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The script below returns the 01427 error that the single row sub-query returns more than one row.  The rownum<2 gets a few rows updated.  The obvious solution is looping through with pl/sql, but I am trying to determine if there is a SQL only solution.

```
UPDATE ldl.clens le
   SET master_song_id =
      (SELECT cf.song_id#
         FROM lt.master_songs cf
        WHERE     le.lot_id = cf.lot_id
              AND song_id#_fk =
                     (SELECT msc_songs.song_id#
                        FROM lt.msc_songs
                       WHERE msc_songs.song_name = le.song_name)
---- AND ROWNUM < 2
);
```

Any and all help and suggestions deeply appreciated!

MD

Comment: Can you execute only the sub query and see what it returns? I believe, your subquery returns more than one value and when you have = operator, you cannot pass more than one value. Also, rownum<2 at the end will be applied at the end for update not for sub queries.

Comment: adding the le table to the sub-query and running it does indeed return multiple song_ids.  I am seeking a SQL only solution that would update each master_song_ids.  the combination of song_id / lot_id creates the unique master_song_id.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of your tables? It will be easier to grasp the relation between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I grasped the relation between the tables, but if I did, you can use below `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE ldl.clens le
   SET master_song_id =
      (SELECT cf.song_id#
         FROM lt.master_songs cf
          JOIN lt.msc_songs ms ON (cf.song_id#_fk = ms.song_id#)
         WHERE
              ms.song_name = le.song_name
          AND le.lot_id = cf.lot_id)
;
```

It will work if `msc_songs.song_name` and `master_songs.lot_id` will give you a unique `master_songs.song_id#`.

Comment: Apologies.. took me a while to get back to this, but your solution works fine... Thank you!!